# Tosca blueprint: how to convert the dictionary output to string

Tags: yaml, cloudify, tosca

In tosca blueprint, I am trying to convert the received the dictionary output to string. However I am unable to find a blueprint method relevant to this. I have added by blueprint below:

```
process:
  args:
    public_ip: { get_attribute: [node1, resources, aws_instance, public_ip] }
    private_ip: { get_attribute: [node1, resources, aws_instance, public_ip] }
```

I am receiving the following error: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, dict found.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if we could see the the node_template in the blueprint.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to read nested properties
If indeed this is what you are trying to achieve, you should point to the right instance in the dict, as in :

`public_ip: { get_attribute: [node1,resources, aws_instance, 1] }`

If you don't, the return value will be whole dict.